# Finding latest document from MongoDB collection using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query

I am a complete beginner with Kotlin and trying to learn MongoDB connections in Android Studio.

I'm trying to find the latest entry in my mongodb collection named `listingsAndReviews`. This is how I instantiate the Client, Database and the Collection and findOne entry with the given query filter using Kotlin in Android Studio.

```
val mongoClient = user!!.getMongoClient("mongodb-atlas") // service for MongoDB Atlas cluster containing custom user data
val mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("sample_airbnb")
val mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("listingsAndReviews")
mongoCollection.count().getAsync { task ->
    if (task.isSuccess) {
        var count = task.get()
        Log.v("EXAMPLE", "successfully counted, number of documents in the collection: $count")
    } else {
        Log.e("EXAMPLE", "failed to count documents with: ${task.error}")
    }
}

val queryFilter = Document("minimum_nights", "2")
mongoCollection.findOne(queryFilter)
    .getAsync { task ->
        if (task.isSuccess) {
            val result = task.get()
            Log.v("EXAMPLE", "successfully found a document: $result")
        } else {
            Log.e("EXAMPLE", "failed to find document with: ${task.error}")
        }
    }
```

I have tested that this query will give me the latest entry in my collection (Mongoose syntax):

`db.collectionName.findOne({}, {sort:{$natural:-1}})`

Could someone please explain how I can write this query in Kotlin or provide any useful resources?

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
mongoCollection.find().sort(Document("_id", -1)).limit(1)
```

Full code:

```
    val cursor: FindIterable<Document> =
        mongoCollection.find().sort(Document("_id", -1)).limit(1)

    cursor.iterator().getAsync { result ->
        if (result != null) {
            val temp = result.get().next()
            //do whatever
        } 
    }
```